# How did Commodore drives produce program listings from disk directories?

Tags: basic, commodore, file-system, disk-drive

CBM BASIC 2.0 has no built-in command for listing the contents of a floppy disk.  Instead, the usual way is to `LOAD` a pseudo-file named `$` from the disk into memory.  The file can then be `LIST`ed like a normal BASIC program.  The listing starts with a header line showing the name and ID of the disk.  Subsequent lines show the size, name, and type of each file.  The final line indicates the amount of free space on the disk:

[image: A screenshot of a Commodore 64 showing a directory listing]

What I'd like to know is how these pseudo-BASIC directory listings are produced.  In particular, is the disk drive itself generating a BASIC listing from the file system and passing it to the computer?  Or is the main computer querying basic file system information from the drive and then constructing the BASIC listing itself?  Also, is the listing really represented in the computer's memory as a (non-functional) BASIC program with line numbers, or is it stored in a dedicated format that the LIST command detects and specially parses?  If the directory is stored as a BASIC program, how is it that two lines can start with the same line number (as is the case when two files have the same size)?

Comment: I always thought this was weird.

Comment: It seems confusing, at first, because the Commodore systems are a bit unique in having CBM-DOS implemented as ROM firmware inside the drive AND executed solely by the drive's CPU.

Comment: I wonder if the story is told on how they got the idea to do it this way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

The computer, or rather its OS, has no idea about a directory, in fact not even what constructs a file. It can only open/read/write/close data streams from devices on the bus. Getting a directory is a clever hack of 'loading' a dummy program. This works since

1. LOAD command is implemented as opening a data stream and loading what is returned into memory at BASIC start.
2. LOAD does not perform any check on the program.
3. LIST command does not perform any checks on syntax or line number sequence.
4. LIST simply outputs what is in BASIC memory by stupidly transforming what is found

As result, a directory listing is quite literally a LISTing (*1).

As so often, Michael Steil did sit down and wrote a [short analysis to directory listing](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=273) on Commodore machines.

---

#### Details

> What I'd like to know is how these pseudo-BASIC directory listings are produced. In particular, is the disk drive itself generating a BASIC listing from the file system and passing it to the computer?

Exactly.

The disk drive creates a pseudo-BASIC-program when the C64 reads from a file named "$".

> Or is the main computer querying basic file system information from the drive and then constructing the BASIC listing itself?

No, the computer, or better the OS, has in fact no idea about a floppy at all. It can access data by using open/read calls send to a device. What is received back will be interpreted as a (program) file.

On the drives side the special file name of "$" is interpreted as command to read the directory(s) (*2) and send the data read back within the framing of "program code":

- Two bytes (offsetted) string length
- Two bytes number of blocks
- A string containing file name and alike (the quotation marks are part of that string).
- A NULL byte at the end

This gets repeated until

- Three NULL in a row (like end of line and next pointer being both NULL) to terminate it.

> Also, is the listing really represented in the computer's memory as a (non-functional) BASIC program with line numbers,

Yes.

In fact, what is delivered only conforms to the rules of a BASIC program as far as the LIST instruction is considered.

> or is it stored in a dedicated format that the LIST command detects and specially parses?

Again, the computer has no idea about things like directories, not even what floppy is, only devices that respond to open/read/write/close instructions on the expansion bus.

It is a rather clever hack to add the functionality of a directory listing to a machine that has no higher level functions beyond initiating and acting upon data streams on the (serial) IEC bus.

It wasn't until after the C64 that Commodore BASIC got a bit more sophisticated by adding disk commands; except they were for most parts just syntactical sugar on top of existing commands/workings.

> If the directory is stored as a BASIC program, how is it that two lines can start with the same line number (as is the case when two files have the same size)?

Not only that, as shown, 'line' numbers even come in non sequential form. This is because the LIST command does not do any syntax or sequence checks. It simply starts at $801 and interprets all bytes as BASIC code. No syntax or sequence checks at all. So whatever bytes are found at the position of a line number is turned from their 16 bit value into readable (ASCII) decimal.

The same goes for outputting all 'program' text. here every byte will taken, compared against the token table and outputted as such, or if not a token, simply as its own value - which opens quite some tricks to add confusion - unless it's in quotation mode, but that's another story.

---

It may be worth to add a 'secret' trick to read a directory (hopefully) without destroying an existing BASIC program. Using a secondary address of '1' like `LOAD "$0",8,1` will load the directory into the screen buffer. The data is stored exactly the way the drive delivers it, thus the display will look quite weird, due the binary nature, but at least file names are pretty clear visible (*3).

This works as the disk controllers create the pseudo program like for the original PET - including the program start address. While the PET had it's BASIC buffer starting at $401, the C64 uses this area as default screen buffer, having BASIC programs starting at $801. Normally, without a secondary address, the pseudo program gets 'relocated' to $801. With `,1` added it will be loaded to the address told by the 'file', which now happens to be the screen bufffer.

A 'tool' that comes very handy when keeping multiple versions of a program on a disk but having forgot what number the last saved version had (*4).

---

*1 - Wouldn't be surprised if that naming similarity made way to that idea :)

*2 - On classic dual drives ([4040](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_4040), etc.) using "$" alone will produce the content of *both* drives - unless qualified for a single drive ("$0" or "$1").

*3 - Since it's a byte for byte representation, tricks used to pretty up a directory entry, hide parts or (simple) protection schemes are visible right away.

*4 - Saving to 'Pn+1' worked great as GIT before GIT

Comment: The disk has knowledge of the file system stored on it, rather than just being (logically) an array of blocks?

Comment: The disk drive's ROM implements the filesystem: it can format a disk, keep track of filenames and file types and where the first block of each file is located, stream data into and out of each file, manage the block allocation map to ensure each block is used only once, handle errors like duplicate names, out-of-space, etc. It can even manage a relative file (direct access file with records). The KERNAL and BASIC 2.0 only know it's device #8 (or #9, etc.) on which it can open files using names and secondary addresses, for reading or writing.

Comment: @another-dave Yes. The drive maintains the file system. somewhat basic, but adequate for the time. That's why Commodore drives were somewhat popular for self build systems, as all needed was a HPIB (Commodore Version) and a very thin layer between application and drive. With the 1450 (Vic20 predecessor of the 1541) even more, as next to every system could bitbang that protocol. Have been countless adaptions. I did connect one to my KIM.

Comment: Oh, so it's more of a file server than just a disk.

Comment: @another-dave Hmm, yes, kinda. I guess one could retrograde call it a file server. More so when considering that the early ones supported multiple drives. Then again, the layers aren't separated as one would expect from a server. Still, around 1979..1984 several classroom solutions were based on multiple commodores sharing a dual drive or hard disk. All needed was adding multi master support to Kernal ROMs. Michael Steil started a [Series about Commodore DOS/drives](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=1018) in 2019, but never really finished. Suggested read if you want to get a good overview.

Comment: So you could try to `run` the `$`pseudo-file and it would just give you a regular syntax error?

Comment: Of possible note, the same concept of the storage device itself handling the filsystem is still used today in some places, such as the USB Media Transfer Protocol (the USB interface used by Android phones for file transfers from a computer, as well as by some portable media players and a lot of cameras). That, and modern hard drives and SSDs actually do quite a lot of work in firmware as well to be able to present the nice block oriented hardware protocols that modern OSes use to access them, the only difference is that they present a block interface instead of a file interface.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: It's a shame compact storage media never adopted something like NFS as the communications protocol, since a flash controller which used a file-base abstraction could be simpler, faster, and more robust than one which effectively has to manage billions of independent 512-byte files.

Comment: @supercat A lot of the same logic would still be needed though even for a file-oriented approach like that, and some of it would actually be somewhat more complicated (wear leveling especially). And, of course, a lot of the same storage overhead would be present, because you still need to track where everything is. There have, however, been attempts at conceptually similar designs, such as the SCSI OSD command set (literally object-storage over SCSI, though it’s largely dead at this point).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: A file-oriented system would not need to support rapid direct random access to billions of different files.  For each file, one could keep a list of the blocks that are used to hold the locations of all the pieces thereof, and that list could also hold the address of a block which is pre-allocated to hold the next updated version thereof.  If it's necessary to update a file, a new block could be pre-allocated to hold a future updated version of the list, and the existing pre-allocated block could be used to hold the new version (including the address of the reserved block).

Comment: "It wasn't until after the C64 that Commodore BASIC got a bit more sophisticated by adding disk commands" - not exactly. The PET 4.0 ROMs had disk commands like CATALOG and DLOAD in 1980, but the VIC-20 and C64 shipped with 2.0 BASIC ROMs.

Comment: @user3486184 well, that's exactly the point. BASIC 4 is after BASIC 2, isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn PET BASIC 4.0 was released before C64 (and VIC) BASIC 2.0.

Comment: @user3486184 But not on the C64. It wasn't until the C128 that DOS commands have been added - and that's the relevant timeline.